# controlling input and output in sas

Tags: input, sas, output

I have this assignment but my professor isn't the best at explaining things. I do not want JUST the answers, but for someone to explain this to me. I'm totally lost.

The data set orion.discount contains information about various discounts that Orion Star runs on its products.
Partial orion.discount

```
    Product_ID    Start_Date     End_Date   Unit_Sales_Price    Discount

  210100100027    01MAY2011    31MAY2011           $17.99      70%
  210100100030    01AUG2011    31AUG2011           $32.99      70%
  210100100033    01AUG2011    31AUG2011          $161.99      70%
  210100100034    01AUG2011    31AUG2011          $187.99      70%
  210100100035    01MAY2011    31MAY2011          $172.99      70%
```

Due to excellent sales, all discounts from December 2011 are repeated in July 2012. Both the December 2011 and the July 2012 discounts are called the Happy Holidays promotion.

1. Create a new data set named work.extended that contains all discounts for the Happy Holidays promotion.
2. Use a WHERE statement to read only observations with a start date of 01Dec2011.
3. Create a new variable, Promotion, which has the value Happy Holidays for each observation.
4. Create another new variable, Season, that has a value of Winter for the December observations and Summer for the July observations.
5. July 2012 discounts should have a start date of 01Jul2012 and an end date of 31Jul2012.
6. Drop the Unit_Sales_Price variable.
7. Use explicit OUTPUT to write two observations for each observation read.

Print the new data set.
Add an appropriate title
Verify the results.

Comment: this looks pretty straight forward.  Post the entire dataset and I'll see if I can produce the result you're looking for with an explanation

Comment: You'll have to explain to us where you got lost.  This looks quite clear for someone who understands the basic concepts and terminology of data bases.  What you've posted -- asking us to further expand on every aspect of your entire assignment -- is well beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

```
data extended;                   /* creates the work.extended dataset
drop unit_sales_price;           /* drops the unit_sales_price from the dataset
set orion.discount;              /* reads from the orion.discount dataset
where start_date = '01DEC2011'd; /* only those records where date matches
Promotion = 'Happy Holidays';    /* create new var
Season = 'Winter';               /* the data step reads in one record at a time
output;                          /* output the first record
Season = 'Summer';               /* change the value of season
Start_date = '01Jul2012'd;       /* change the value of start and end date
End_date = '31Jul2012'd;
output;                          /* output second record
```